# HTML5 JavaScript API / getUserMedia - best way to store a video + audio snapshots when user speaks

Tags: javascript, html5-video, getusermedia

I am interested what is the best solution, and how to store short video+audio snapshots, **only for moments when user speaks**.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: It will really depend on your capacities, stackoverflow is not the place to write you such a piece of code. So to answer your questions, the best way is to learn how to do it (not so complicated actually), start by looking in the audioAPI for the speaking threshold. Then look at some plugins like [RecordRTC](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/) to save the stream. Then if you face some difficulties doing so, you can come back here with specific questions.

Comment: I will close th question

Comment: Thanks for feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a cross browser solution!
Unfortunately there is none...

You have to use flash + js fallback for modern browsers
I have searched for a solution for this my self few weeks ago and eventually used the HDFVR cam which has a flash recorder with js fallback for mobile

There are few ways record video + audio in html5 that are not that simple as it sounds
As Arjit said webRTC is the best and solution for now but not capable with all browsers

It supports FF Video + Audio recording
Chrome Video and Audio as divided tracks and then you need to decode them together

About opera and IE no better solutions

So as i said i have used HDFVR for this with a RED5 server
The best solution i've found so far https://hdfvr.com/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

Comment: My pleasure..... By the way I understand how you feel i've been in the same situation.... and got real frustrated with this